# Modified Majority function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote the Majority sql query for oracle as mentioned at:
[Majority function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533290/majority-function-in-sql/22534169#22534169)

But my requirement is slightly different. If no column value found as majority then a single row with null value should be returned in the query. I tried somthing like:

```
select CASE WHEN count(*) > 0 THEN tbl2.DATA ELSE NULL END AS "Majority_column1_" from (
select distinct DATA
from (
  select DATA, NAME,
         count(*) over () as total_count, 
         count(*) over (partition by DATA) as DATA_count
  from MAJORITY_TEST
) tbl1 where tbl1.DATA_count > tbl1.total_count / 2) tbl2;
```

Idea is check if the total no. of rows returned is > 0 then return the row value as it is else return null. But syntactically it incorrect.

Could someone suggest me a correct query for the same.

Thanks

Comment: You need to return total_count as a column from the inline view, then reference that in your CASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your definition of majority meaning 50% of occurrences are that value, you can only have zero or one value returned. So, you can just use `max()`:

```
select max(DATA)
from (
  select DATA, NAME,
         count(*) over () as total_count, 
         count(*) over (partition by DATA) as DATA_count
  from MAJORITY_TEST
) tbl1 where tbl1.DATA_count > tbl1.total_count / 2;
```

With data where there is a majority value:

```
insert into majority_test (data, name)
select 10, 'A' from dual
union all select 20, 'B' from dual
union all select 20, 'C' from dual
union all select 20, 'D' from dual;
```

This gives:

```
 MAX(DATA)
----------
        20
```

The aggregate function means you don't need the `distinct`. Without a majority, via `update majority_test set data = 10 where name = 'D'`, the same query gives:

```
 MAX(DATA)
----------
```

i.e. a single row with a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to get the value.  Do the calculation for `data_count` and `total_count`.  Then choose the row with the largest `data_count` value.  If this passes the threshold, output the `DATA` value.  Otherwise, output `NULL`:

```
select (case when data_count > total_count / 2 then DATA end)
from (select DATA, 
             count(*) as DATA_count, over () as data_count, 
             sum(count(*)) over () as total_count
      from MAJORITY_TEST
      group by DATA
      order by data_count desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Note that the subquery uses explicit aggregation with an analytic function.  This is just an alternative approach.